# Google Analytics User Account

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web app that uses Google Analytics that is hosted on http://example.com. The following Google Analytics JS is included in every page

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-99999999-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function () {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');
    ga.type = 'text/javascript';
    ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 'stats.g.doubleclick.net/dc.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Am I correct in assuming that the account ID above `'UA-99999999-1'` refers to my Google Analytics account?

If I run the application locally, or on any domain other than `example.com`, will any traffic thereon also be sent to my GA account, or does this account ID only work when the application is running on the domain associated with the GA account (example.com)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are firing this Google Analytics Tracking Code (GATC) on your development environment then this will be sending requests to Google and will appear in your reports.

If you wanted to keep your development, test and production environments separate then you could create separate profiles, e.g.

```
UA-9999999-1 for PRODUCTION
UA-9999999-2 for TEST
UA-9999999-3 for DEV
```

Have a look here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite - this might be of interest.

Comment: is it possible to configure Google Analytics, such that all requests except those from `example.com` are ignored?